# Converting a single list element within a list to multiple elements within the containing list (in place)

Tags: python

**This is not converting a 2d list to a 1d list.  This is converting a list element (which happens to be a list) to multiple elements within the containing list.  The input is not a list of lists.**

I have a list like the following:

```
x = [1, [2,3,4], 5,....]
```

I want to convert it to this:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I know something like the following will work:

```
y = []
for _ in x:
  if isinstance(_, list):
   for i in _:
     y.append(i)
  else:
    y.append(_)
```

But was hoping there was some more pythonic way like the following (obviously won't work):

```
x = [2, _ for _ in [2,3,4], 5]
```

Comment: Side note, a single underscore `_` is usually reserved [for throwaway variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893186/4518341), so using it here is confusing.

Comment: Side note, instead of `for i in _: y.append(i)`, it's simpler to do `y.extend(_)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Comment: @wjandrea, it doesn't directly answer the question.  The code in my question isn't really different than any of those answers.  The answer seems to be "There is no way to flatten a single list element in place" or the answer I accepted which is "here is a clever way to solve this in python" although not exactly what I was attempting to do.

Comment: @wjandrea the point was the "_" would be a throwaway variable that temporarily stores the list element.  No different than the following [_ for _ in [2,3,4]].

Comment: "Throwaway" means you don't actually use it. Where you reference it later, that means it's not a throwaway name. So I would change it to something like `for item in x: if isinstance(item, list): ...`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946/4518341) has some examples of actual throwaways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this (making a list homogeneous and then combining the elements):

```
>>> x = [1, [2, 3, 4], 5]
>>> sum([[i] if not isinstance(i, list) else i for i in x], [])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Another solution with `functool.reduce`:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> a = [1, [2, 3, 4], 5]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: [x] + y if not isinstance(x, list) else (x + [y] if not isinstance(y, list) else x + y), a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This will work.  If looping over all list elements in the only way to do this, I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @user2263572 I added another solution with `reduce` which recursively processes the list with no _explicit_ loop

Answer (score 0):

Let me do you one better. Let's assume that the elements themselves can be lists containing other elements. for example something like this:
`[1,[2,3,[4,5,6],[[4,5],6]]]`

You can do a dfs (depth-first-search) to collapse them into a single list

```py
def dfs(elem):
  if isinstance(elem, int):
    return [elem]
  else:
    ret = []
    
    for i in elem:
      ret += dfs(i)
    return ret
```

If you just want it for a single depth and really pythonic, then this will do:

```py
sum([[i] if isinstance(i, int) else i for i in x],[])
```